# c# string to enum mapping

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following Enum:

```
public enum ItemType
{
   Foo =0,
   Bar =1
}
```

and then a string that is passed to a method in lowercase.

How can I compare the string to my enum and return the enum.

```
public ItemType Method(string value)
{
   ///compare string to enum here and return Enum
}
```

and the method receives the value as parameter like this (notice the lowercase)

```
string value = "foo";  /// or value ="bar"

ItemType type = Method(value)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
public ItemType Method(string value)
{
    ItemType item;
    if(Enum.TryParse(value, true, out item)) return item;

    else /* throw exception or return defaul value  */
}
```

The second parameter is allows you to perform case insensitive search.